# How to shrink text to fit when single words are too long for a UILabel width in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uilabel

I have a square UILabel that will show one word only. However, when that word is too long, it cuts off the word, instead of shrinking it down to fit.

How do I get the UILabel to shrink to fit a single word?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can used the `AutoShrink` property of `UILabel`. Please find the below screenshot for the same.

[image: Screenshot]

1. Select the `AutoShrink` property.
2. Click on the Minimum Font Size option
3. Adjust any value depend on your requirement once the text will shrink.

Please refer the below GIF represenation.

[image: GIF]

Hope it works for you!!!

Comment: The is the best answer I have ever seen for a question, I love the GIF. However, the label I am using has 3 lines, but sometimes, I do not need to use 3 lines as I have only 1 word to show, but it does not auto shrink, but start a new line to finish showing the word?